# Codeigniter affected_rows always returning 0 when rows inserted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, error-handling

Im doing an insert to a table and the script should only continue if the update inserts correctly.

```
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){}
```

Works perfectly fine else where in my application but for some reason at one point it doesnt and always returns 0

the snippet is as followed

```
while($asked_order_amount_needed > 0){

$matches_attempted = 0;
$matched_orders = $query->result_array();
foreach($matched_orders as $matched_order){

//we can fill the submitted order completely with a matched order with a higher volume then the ask volume so try this first
if($matched_order['amount'] >= $ask['amount']){


$ask_history = array(
'order_type' => $ask['order_type'],
 'amount' => $ask['amount'],
 'price' => $ask['price'],
 'entry_by' => $ask['entry_by'],
 'status' => 'filled',
 'buy_currency_name' => $ask['buy_currency_name'],
 'sell_currency_name' => $ask['sell_currency_name'],
 'timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);

$dump = $this->db->insert('tb_order_book_history', $ask_history);
//$sql = $this->db->last_query();

if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
```

I added `$dump =` infront of the `$this->db->insert('tb_order_book_history',$ask_history);`

Just for debugging to check the output, which returns true and i've copied the `$sql` value of

```
$sql = $this->db->last_query();
```

run it through MySQL work bench which inserts it fine, ive also checked the table after running the application through this function and the data is being inserted fine. Now unless i've been staring at the code too long and missing something really simple, i have no idea why it's behaving like this.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: use 'timestamp' => '2015-05-19 15:00:00' (fixed date string) and see what happens, if it fails again, enable all error messages set db_debug to TRUE and log_threshold to 4 , check the logs, and start debugging and checking logs to see what happens, because this depends on many things

Comment: its probably because of your other lines of codes, or other functions (because u say the issue is only on some pages) , so it can't be detected by what you posted

Comment: i always dev with debugging on and xdebug and nothing is generating errors, I edited my snippet above to show the start of the while loop. Only thing before that is a select query to pull orders from an order book which doesn't generate any errors either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$this->db->affected_rows()` why don't you try it along with `$this->db->insert_id()`. You can use it as same way as

```
$this->db->insert('tb_order_book_history',$ask_history);
$dump = $this->db->insert_id();

if(!empty($dump) && $dump > 0){
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this is the answer as the best one provided. A cleaner method i ended up using to avoid extra function call is just checking the return value as TRUE like this.

if($this->db->insert('tb_order_book_history', $ask_history) == TRUE){}

All work as well but i want as few additional functions in this method to keep execution time to a minimum